# Проблема с кодом предзагрузки изображений

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет.Есть необходимость реализовать предзагрузку изображений на странице. вариант с метатегом  не очень подходит, так как слишком ново и не все бразуеры поддерживают. Пробовал вставлять найденный код предзагрузки на JQuery

```
$.preloadImages = function () {
    if (typeof arguments[arguments.length - 1] == 'function') {
        var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
    } else {
        var callback = false;
    }

    if (typeof arguments[0] == 'object') {
        var images = arguments[0];
        var n = images.length;
    } else {
        var images = arguments;
        var n = images.length - 1;
    }
    var not_loaded = n;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        jQuery(new Image()).attr('src', images[i]).load(function() {
            if (--not_loaded < 1 &amp;&amp; typeof callback == 'function') {
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Но в консоле вылезает ошибка синтаксиса..у меня в файле со скриптами все функции подключены следующим образом `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`
Кто подскажет, что я делаю не так?Или как лучше реализовать предзагрузку изображений..Изображения не маленькие, фоновые, почти на весь экран.

Comment: Какая именно ошибка вылезает? Копипаст из консоли, пожалуйста

Comment: первая строка - SyntaxError: missing ) after condition

Comment: вторая строка - TypeError: $.preloadImages is not a function

Comment: 1) Где-то пропустили закрывающую скобку ")" после выражение 2)Возможно, ошибка в имени функции, попробуйте убрать точку, чтобы получилось  $preloadImages

Comment: я понимаю что значат эти ошибки так как с английским дружу, но вот я пробовал всяко закрывать скобки, результат тот же..код привел полностью как он есть у меня...ты видишь ошибку?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать точку в начале названия функции и убрать знак доллара, из-за него браузер может воспринимать функцию как глобальный объект, в этом может быть ошибка

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61493/discussion-between-deniskins-and-klimenkomud).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так валидатор не ругается

```
$.preloadImages = function () { 
if (typeof arguments[arguments.length - 1] == 'function') { 
var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1]; 
} else { 
var callback = false; 
} 

if (typeof arguments[0] == 'object') { 
var images = arguments[0]; 
var n = images.length; 
} else { 
var images = arguments; 
var n = images.length - 1; 
} 
var not_loaded = n; 
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
jQuery(new Image()).attr('src', images[i]).load(function() { 
if (--not_loaded < 1 && typeof callback == 'function') { 
callback(); 
} 
}); 
}
```